# Cómo puedo hacer que se visualice en smart tv lo que estoy viendo en mi celular?

Tags: android, cast

quisiera saber de que manera puedo hacer o mandar el video que estoy viendo en mi celular a una smart tv?

Algo así como lo hace youtube en su app.

Me serviria mucho si me dijeran que librerias o funciones debo de usar para porder lograr esa visualización en una pantalla de tv desde mi celular por medio de internet, estoy utilizando android studio.

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Desarrollo con dongles

- Google cast https://developers.google.com/cast/
- Roku https://www.roku.com/developer

Desarrollo para smart TV

- LG Smart TV http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/
- Samsung Smart TV https://www.samsungdforum.com/

La tecnologia usada para hacer mirror es  [Miracast](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast)

---

Si desarrollas con android nativo puedes usar [Media Router](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]